# Why google map Polyline not showing (in Chrome)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google map to show markers,
then I want to use polyline to link markers one by one.
but polyline doesn't showing.
my code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    /*map initial*/
    var mapOptions = {
        ...
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    /*draw markers*/
    var tmp_user_location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.772,-122.214);
    var tmp_marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: tmp_user_location1,
        map: map
    });
    var tmp_user_location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(21.291,-157.821);
    var tmp_marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: tmp_user_location2,
        map: map
    });
    arr_markers.push(tmp_marker1);
    arr_markers.push(tmp_marker2);
    /*draw polyline*/
    arr_user_location_polyline.push(tmp_user_location1);
    arr_user_location_polyline.push(tmp_user_location2);
    var user_location_path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        paths: arr_user_location_polyline,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: "#FF00FF",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    user_location_path.setMap(map);
}
```

[screen capture picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkcfT.png)
any one help?
thanks a lot.

Comment: where are you creating `arr_user_location_polyline`?  What's the contents of that variable if you write it out to the console at the time you're trying to create the Polyline?  Are you getting any javascript errors?  Can you see the polyline if you zoom out?  Where's the map centered on?  What's the contents of `mapOptions`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that a [google.maps.PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions) object doesn't have a `paths` property (a google.maps.Polygon does), it has a `path` property.

```
var user_location_path = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: arr_user_location_polyline,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: "#FF00FF",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
```

If I fix that, and the javascript errors in the posted code:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: arr_markers is not defined
- Uncaught ReferenceError: arr_user_location_polyline is not defined

I get a polyline:  [proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pmywmr0w/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr_markers = [];
  var arr_user_location_polyline = [];
  /*map initial*/
  var mapOptions = {
    center: {
      lat: 21.291,
      lng: -157.821
    },
    zoom: 3
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
  /*draw markers*/
  var tmp_user_location1 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.772, -122.214);
  var tmp_marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: tmp_user_location1,
    map: map
  });
  var tmp_user_location2 = new google.maps.LatLng(21.291, -157.821);
  var tmp_marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: tmp_user_location2,
    map: map
  });
  arr_markers.push(tmp_marker1);
  arr_markers.push(tmp_marker2);
  /*draw polyline*/
  arr_user_location_polyline.push(tmp_user_location1);
  arr_user_location_polyline.push(tmp_user_location2);
  var user_location_path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: arr_user_location_polyline,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF00FF",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  user_location_path.setMap(map);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: thanks to geocodezip,but it still not work,and there has no any exception. global_polyline_array is not null or empty, i dump this array as follow: